# How do I solve * Multiply two 8 bit data and store in 6000 location and onwards * in MSDOS For masm 8086?

Tags: assembly, memory, x86-16

[Emulation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhfgR.png)

I was asked to Multiply two 8 bit and show the output in 6000 memory location but am unable to do so i can get output with RET without memory location in  AX only.

```
MYCODE SEGMENT
ASSUME cs:MYCODE
    ORG 1000h
START:
    nop
L1: mov ax, cs
    mov ds, ax
    mov sp, ax
    mov bx, 3000h
L2: mov al, 10h
    mov ah, 10h
L3: MUL al
    mov BYTE PTR ds:[bx+3000h], al
    HLT

L4: mov ah, 4CH
    INT 21H

MYCODE ENDS
END START
```

Comment: More information on what you are multiplying would be helpful. But `mov sp, ax` is not good. You are setting the stack pointer to the value of the CS register. What are the labels for? You don't use them. Why HLT?  `mul al` does not use the value in `ah`.

Comment: `org 1000h` is wrong for a .com executable, and .exe executables shouldn't use `org`, I thought.  Not that it matters; none of your code uses any symbols for absolute addresses.    You get to an offset of `6000h` with `3000h+3000h` for some reason, instead of just using it directly; I don't see the point of not just using `[6000h]` or putting that value in BX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mul al` multiplies AL by AL and puts the result in AX. Since you set AL to 10h, the result is AX=100h and then you store AL which is zero. If you want to multiply AL by AH and store the result you should do this:

```
mul ah
mov WORD PTR ds:[bx+3000h], ax
```

You also need to remember that 8086 is little-endian so when you store AX to 6000h, the byte at 6000h will be 0x00 and the byte at 6001h will be 0x10.